# Code errors in PhpStorm 2018 after using Alt+Enter on "src" attribute in <script> tag

Tags: attributes, tags, phpstorm, settings

[image]

I was clicked on `src` attribute and selected like library or something like that and now I have this "wrong code". I want to revert it. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Please provide screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`. Only interested in entries with `IDE` or `Project` in `Scope` column.

Comment: Thank you,JQL on src attributes was placed,removed and all work fine again! Thank you LazyOne !

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you have some language injected in `<script>` `src` attribute. Please check language injections with `IDE` and `Project` scope in **Preferences | Editor | Language Injections**